# How to keep good code practices in a specific case (c++)

Tags: c++

So, basically, i have a struct, let's say `struct someStruct {int x; int y;};` (**only as a example**), and a class. For my specific situation, `x` must be able to be changed from any scope, but `y` should only be changed from inside the class.

I have no idea of what I'm supposed to do here. I have thought about making `y` a private property of the class, but it wouldn't make much sense since `y` is a property of my struct, and separating it from the struct would make it way too unclear.

If you need more details (**i don't see why you would since there's really not much to describe**, but i'm putting here anyways), my struct is:

```
typedef struct {

    // A, B, C, position, transform and material should be changed from any scope (don't bother with what they mean, it's not important for the purposes of this question)
    vec2 A;
    vec2 B;
    vec2 C;
    vec2 position;
    mat2 transform;
    Material material;

    // this should only be changed from inside the class.
    // it identifies the buffer that sends the information of this triangle to the GPU,
    // and makes no sense from any scope outside the class
    int buffer;
} Triangle;
```

and my class is (basically):

```
class Renderer {

    // note: many triangles will be stored per buffer, so I can't just assign one buffer to one triangle and vice-versa
    GLuint *buffers;
    Triangle* triangles;

    // + some stuff to handle rendering and blah blah blah
}
```

If you *really* want it, I can post the full code, but I don't think it could be useful in any way so for now i'm not posting it

preferably try answering the general situation, so I actually learn something from this question, but a more specific answer is very welcome too (e.g. store buffer and triangle data in another way)

Comment: Make `B` private and declare `Renderer` as friend.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are the same thing except `struct` defaults to `public` access and `class` defaults to ``private`. If you want to make it private you can.

Comment: but i wouldnt be able to change B from my class, or would i?

Comment: Or make `Triangle` private and add a getter and setter for `A`.

Comment: Use someStruct for example at first ,but Triangle and Renderer behind make people confuse.

Comment: @jabaa well, i never heard about that feature (declaring as a friend), but it looks like its going to work from my quick google search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `B` private and declare `Renderer` as friend, e.g.:

```
struct Triangle {
    friend class Renderer;
    // A, B, C, position, transform and material should be changed from any scope (don't bother with what they mean, it's not important for the purposes of this question)
    vec2 A;
    private:
        vec2 B;
    public:
        vec2 C;
        vec2 position;
        mat2 transform;
        Material material;

        // this should only be changed from inside the class.
        // it identifies the buffer that sends the information of this triangle to the GPU,
        // and makes no sense from any scope outside the class
        int buffer;
};

class Renderer {
    public:
        // note: many triangles will be stored per buffer, so I can't just assign one buffer to one triangle and vice-versa
        GLuint *buffers;
        Triangle* triangles;
        void setB(vec2 b) { triangles->B = b; } // no error
        // + some stuff to handle rendering and blah blah blah
};

int main() {
    Renderer renderer;
    renderer.triangles = new Triangle;
    renderer.triangles->A = vec2(1,2); // no error
    renderer.setB(vec2(1,2)); // no error
    renderer.triangles->B = vec2(1,2); // error: 'vec2 Triangle::B' is private within this context
}
```